# Superpowered audio player pause at position

Tags: ios, http-live-streaming, superpowered

I'm streaming audio using `_audioPlayer->openHLS()` and I need to start and stop at specific positions.

The best way seems to be to use `loopBetween` and then call `exitLoop` in the LoopEnd event. However, I can't get `loopBetween` to play!

```
    _audioPlayer->loopBetween(startTimeMS, stopTimeMs, true, 255, false);
```

I have tried calling `_audioPlayer->play(false)` before or after the `loopBetween`, but then the audio plays without stopping. If I just call `loopBetween` it never starts playing.

Is there some config I'm missing to get `loopBetween` to work? The SDK has no sample code covering looping.

EDIT: I've found one way to do this, by polling `positionMs` in the audio processing callback. I'd still like to know how to make looping work, as that seems like a cleaner solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looping doesn't work for HLS streams. Polling positionMs in the audio processing callback is a perfect solution.